# Problems with intance of my DataReader Class

Tags: java, android, singleton, populate

I have some trouwble with my custom class to get Data. I've created one custom class for get data from my web service, the issue comes when I try to use my singleton class, If I use `DataReader.getInstance(getContext(), this)`  my listview is populated only the first time when app starts. But if I use a new instance of my DataReader work fine in anytime..

Here my DataReader Class:

```
public class DataReader {
private static DataReader singleton;
private Context context;
private Data_Listener data_listener;

public DataReader(Context context, Data_Listener data_listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data_listener = data_listener;
}

public static synchronized DataReader getInstance(Context context, Data_Listener data_listener) {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new DataReader(context, data_listener);
    }

    return singleton;
}

public void Categorias_fill(){
    final ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    API.getInstance(context).unAuthenticateArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, context.getString(R.string.endpoint_categorias), null, new API_Listener() {
        @Override
        public void OnSuccess(JSONObject response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void OnSuccess(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Categoria categoria;
            for(int i = 0;i < response.length(); i++) {
                categoria = gson.fromJson(response.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Categoria.class);
                objects.add(categoria);
            }
            data_listener.onBindData(objects);
        }

        @Override
        public void OnError(String error) {
            data_listener.onBindData(objects);
        }

    });
}
```

and here how I used DataReader:

```
public class CategoriasFragment extends Fragment implements Data_Listener{
private Categorias_Adapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Categoria> list = new ArrayList<>();
private ExpandableListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categorias, container, false);
    listView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if(list.size()>0){
                if(list.get(groupPosition).getSubCategorias().size()>0){
                    SubCategoria subCategoria = list.get(groupPosition).getSubCategorias().get(childPosition);
                    Log.d(General.appname, subCategoria.getNombre());
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    //This work only the first time
    //DataReader.getInstance(getContext(), this).Categorias_fill();

    //This work everytime
    DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(getContext(), this);
    dataReader.Categorias_fill();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onBindData(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
    list = (ArrayList) objects;
    adapter = new Categorias_Adapter(getContext(), list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In subsequent calls to `getInstance()` your context and Data_Listener are not getting set. They'll still point to whatever they pointed to with the first call.

I suggest trying this: explicitly set DataReader.context and DataReader.data_listener inside your getInstance() method.